# MS Dynamics GP and cost accounting

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

Is cost accounting native to GP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering own question - yes it is

Answer (score 0):

Project Accounting is the name for the application provided by Microsoft Dynamics GP.
It is hard to learn and hard to use so I generally convince my clients to use Olympic Project Cost instead.  You have to pay for OLYPC but the money isn't huge and it's likely you would spend more that the cost of OLYPC in extra implementation and testing costs.